# Надёжность сигналов-слотов

Tags: алгоритм, qt, c++

Всем привет!

Представьте
Программа, выполняющая сканирование сайтов на предмет обновлений
Допустим, в БД 50 сайтов = 50 сканирующих "потоков"...
В каждом "потоке" - скачка html-кода из интернета, парсинг, внесение в БД...

Я специально закавычил слово "поток", потому что, в данном случае, использование потоков не обязательно...

Важно другое

Как организовать такую работу наиболее правильным "архитектурно-технологически" способом?
Мне просто интересны варианты :)

Уже пробовал создавать отдельный поток под каждый сайт, но проблема в том, что сканирование сайтов (читай - использование QWebPage) необходимо делать в [b]главном (GUI) потоке[/b]
К тому же, этот механизм не показал особой стабильности...
Может, из-за корявости реализации, не использования QthreadPool'ов (ксттаи, интересно, насколько хорош QThreadPool))

Сейчас делаю так...(просто пример, но суть работы та же, что и в программе)
**Analyzer**

```
class Analyzer : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Analyzer();
    ~Analyzer();
public slots:
    void analyze(QString str);
private:
    QList<Timer *> m_timers;
};

Analyzer::Analyzer() {
    //запускаем 100 таймеров
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        Timer *timer = new Timer(10000, i);
        m_timers.push_back(timer);
        connect(timer, SIGNAL(analyze(QString)),
                this, SLOT(analyze(QString))
                );
    }
}

Analyzer::~Analyzer() {
    for (int i = 0; i < m_timers.size(); i++) {
        delete m_timers[i];
    }
}

void Analyzer::analyze(QString str) {
    qDebug() << "Timer " + str;
}
```

**Timer**

```
class Timer : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Timer(int interval, int number);
    ~Timer();

public slots:
    void needAnalyze();

signals:
    void analyze(QString str);

private:
    int m_number;
    QTimer *m_timer;
};
Timer::Timer(int interval, int number) {
    m_timer = new QTimer(this);
    //раз в 10 секунд
    m_timer->start(interval);

    connect(m_timer, SIGNAL(timeout()),
            this,    SLOT(needAnalyze())
            );

    m_number = number;
}

Timer::~Timer() {
    m_timer->stop();
    delete m_timer;
}

void Timer::needAnalyze() {
    emit analyze(QString::number(m_number));
}
```

То есть, есть класс анализатора, в котором создаются потоки, и каждый из них вызывает через определённое время сигнал о том, что необходимо произвести анализ
То есть, всё построено на механизме сигналов-слотов

Но, при "большом" объёме сайтов (примерно 20-30) - прога заваливается, и либо не сканирует какие-то сайты, либо не работает вообще

И я не могу определить, в чём тут проблема!
То есть, если брать 5 +-5 сайтов, то работа стабильна, а чуть больше - глючит
Дело ли тут в том, что механизм сигналов-слотов даёт сбой, или где-то в алгоритме ошибка (но прога ведь не падает..)?

**Отсюда вопросы:**

1. Насколько надёжно, на Ваш взгляд,
       использование механизма
       сигналов-слотов
2. Насколько оно надёжно в приведённом
       случае
3. Насколько рнационален, на Ваш
       взгляд, предложенный мной подход к
       решению проблемы
4. Ну и вообще, Ваше мнение на сей счёт

Вопросов много накатал...
Буду рад, если кто-нибудь ответит :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

То, что вы описали - классический пример задачи, где из коробки работает паттерн [Producer-Consumer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem) с общим буфером.

Пусть есть некоторый `unit of work` - задача по проверки обновления содержимого **одного сайта**. И пусть есть объект `Producer`, который делает следующие действия: создает некоторую абстракцию `UnitOfWork`, куда складывает адрес сайта, его текущую выкачанную копию и какую-то вспомогательную информацию, **эта абстракция записывается в буфер.** Третий объект - `Consumer`, который получает на вход объект `UnitOfWork` и на его основании делает вывод о том, обновилась страница или нет и *совершает необходимые действия.*

---

Теперь запускаем `MAX_ALLOWED_PRODUCERS`, которые будут выполнять по одной из 50 исходных задач. Они будут заполнять некоторый буфер `(который лучше всего делать по принципу`FIFO`)`. Одновременно с этим запускаем `MAX_ALLOWED_CONSUMERS`, которые забирают задачи из буфера по мере их поступления. **Каждый из них выполняется в отдельном потоке.** По мере выполнения этих самых задач нужно добавлять новых `Producer'ов` и `Consumer'ов`.

Константы количества задач можно определить, например, исходя из параметров сети и количества ядер. *Я бы не стал бы делать их больше, чем 10, т.к просто невыгодно.*
 **В конкретно вашем случае имеет смысл схема "много `Producer'ов` - один `Consumer`", т.к операция скачивания занимает намного больше времени, нежели соответствующая обработка.**

---

Сигналы из `Qt` здесь могут использоваться, например, когда необходимо результат `Consumer` положить в вашу базу данных *(хотя, на мой взгляд, это все намного прозрачнее выглядит без использования сигналов вообще)*.

---

#### Update

---

На схему `Producer-Consumer` ваше замечание о необходимости обновления в `X` секунд никак не влияет. Другое дело, что в таком случае нужно добавить некоторую планировку взамен простого добавления `UnitOfWork` в общий буфер.

*Вариантов, опять же, несколько.* Если бы я реализовывал подобную функциональность, то я бы, предположительно, видоизменил схему работы следующим образом: использовал бы **одного** `Producer'а` и **множество** `Consumer'ов`. Таким образом, `Producer` используется для планирования и генерации задач, т.е спавнит некоторые `UnitOfWork`, которые содержат адрес и максимальное время, за которое задача должна быть выполнена *(т.е `currentTime() + 5 или 60 или X секунд`)*.

Дальше - есть некоторое количество `Consumer'ов`, которые все эти задачи вытаскивают *(по очереди)*, скачивают соответствующие страницы и обновляют базу данных. В случае, если какой-то `Consumer` не успевает выполнить задачу в установленный срок, то, например, может швырнуть `Exception` или пометить задачу как *невыполненную в срок.*

Дальше, в зависимости от того, насколько хорошо хочется все сделать, можно добавить, например, **интрузивного планировщика задач,** *который будет переставлять их в более грамотном порядке и, скажем, вручную перезапускать задачи, которые закончились невыполненными в срок.*

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ:)
Есть пара вопросов...
1. У нас такая система...что сканирование сайтов нужно проводить по времени...
Допустим, часть сайтов раз в минуту, часть раз в 5 минут, а потом могут появиться новые сайты, или таймер обновления может поменяться...
Как быть в такой ситуации?
2. Вот Вы пишете, что Consumer должен выполняться в отдельном потоке...
Но ведь он один?
И как быть, если сайты имеют разный таймер, ведь будет сдвиг во времени...
Понимаю, что это не критично, но всё же

Comment: @Lindemann66 Ответил апдейтом.